# How to prove the following problem on Hermitian matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ M $ be an $ n\times n $ Hermitian matrix of rank $ k $, $k\neq n$. If $\lambda $ $\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $ M $ with corresponding unit column vector $ u $, with $ Mu= \lambda  u$,then Which of the following are true?

1. rank ($ M-\lambda $ $uu^* $) =$ k-1 $
2. $ ( M- \lambda uu^* )^n =  M^n- \lambda^n uu^* $

I think both are true, I considered some examples which is obviously not the right way to solve the above problem. I tried to use the fact that any Hermitian matrix is unitarily diagonalizable  to show the 2nd option , but I couldn't do it.

please give me some  hints . Thanks in advance.

Comment: \lambda not \lamda

Comment: Diagonalisation works perfectly here. At what step did you fail?

Comment: Thank you, I am trying again ,If I fail again I will edit my post .

Comment: Pay attention that it is a *unitary* diagonalisation, i.e. the columns (eigenvectors) of a transformation matrix are mutually orthogonal (including $u$, in particular).

Comment: Thank you sir,  I am trying to solve it